# Python modified a list of words

Tags: python, list

I am new to Python and have some problems.

I have a csv file with 1000 sentences. I am trying to clean all of the sentences by removing words that have no meaning using nltk. I have imported the csv and make it a list called mylist. When I am using for loop to clean the texts for each item in the list, I encountered TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str. Once I am done cleaning the texts, I would like to export it back to csv.

Thanks in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk 
nltk.download('words')
words = set(nltk.corpus.words.words())


uscomment = r'C:\Users\John\Desktop\us_final_dataset.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(uscomment)
mylist = df['us_comment'].tolist()
new_lists = []


for i in mylist:
    mylist[i]= " ".join(w for w in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(mylist[i]) if w.lower() in words or not w.isalpha())
    new_lists.append(mylist)
```

Comment: Lists items are words but when You write 'mylist[i]', The i index must be a number, and The for loop as it is on your code put the words on the list inside the variable i, instead the index number of the word.

Comment: @ArthurJulião more suited as an answer then as a comment

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the sentences directly using:

```
df['us_comment'] = df['us_comment'].apply()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running this:

```py
for i in ["a", "b", "c"] :
  print(i)
```

so in your case an example would be: `mylist["someword"]` while you want something like `mylist[1]`

As you can see, it prints the values, not the indicies, you want the indices.

```
for i in range(len(mylist)):
```

Range generates an inclusive exclusive range, so `range(3)` generates `0, 1, 2`,excluding the 3. Which is good, because a list of length 3 has exactly those indexes. The last element of a list of length n has the index n-1, as indexing starts at 0

Answer (score 0):

Lists items are words but when You write `mylist[i]`, The `i` index must be a number, and the `for` loop as it is on your code put the words on the list inside the variable `i`, instead the index number of the index number of that word.